# LIRCsharp in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, lirc

I have been trying to find example code for the LIRC sharp package on Visual Studio and am unable to find anything of use.

I am trying to code a Raspberry Pi running Windows core 10 (IoT, so C#) for use as both a remote receiver and emitter, but with my less than basic knowledge am unable to find the resources to even make a start.

So the question is does anyone have example code using the LIRCsharp reference in VS 2015, which they are willing to share with me?